# Change grails resource default action names/labels

Tags: grails

When we use the resource attribute to define a mapping like "/api/user"(resource: 'user') the following mappings are created by Grails:

```
"/api/user/create"(controller: 'user', action: 'create', method: 'GET')
"/api/user/edit"(controller: 'user', action: 'edit', method: 'GET')
"/api/user(.(*))?"(controller: 'user', action: 'delete', method: 'DELETE')
"/api/user(.(*))?"(controller: 'user', action: 'update', method: 'PUT')
"/api/user(.(*))?"(controller: 'user', action: 'save', method: 'POST')
```

Well, what I want to do it to change these defaults so that I can translate the actions to my native language. So when I create a resource, I want those actions to be: "criar, editar, deletar, atualizar, salvar".

Is that possible? How can I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably write a new RestfulController implementation (basing on @Resource AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) annotation, which we can use as the superClass).

Check this out: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/07/grails-goodness-custom-controller-class.html

And base on RestfulController implemetation:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy

Comment: That seems promising. Thanks, I'll try that.